# which is better way to casting in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

In my coding various places i need to change integer values to string values. To convert the cast integer to string i use **concatenation with "" to integer**.

i found an another way that is using **String.parseInt(..);** method.

my question is i do not know which is optimized method to do casting in java and how it is optimized?. is there any other way to cast except my code?

my sample code:

```
int total = mark1 + mark2;
String str_total = ""+total;  // currently doing.
```

.......

```
String str_total = String.parseInt(total);  // i am planning to do.
```

Comment: got two questions for you; 1) how many times do you intend on doing this operation? (in other words can you justify the need for optimization?) and 2) did you try to benchmark it? :)

Comment: There is no parseInt method in String. You probably meant valueOf.

Comment: i want good coding for performance wise so that i need optimize.

Comment: If you just use it a few times (as opposed to a few thousand times at least), code readability is more important than performance, because you will not win more than a few microseconds from that...

Comment: Beware the dangers of premature optimizations and particularly micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use -

```
String str_total = String.valueOf(total);
```

OR

Use Integer rahter than int in your code and then use toString() on Integer like

```
Integer total = mark1 + mark2;
String str_total = total.toString();
```

In your code -

String str_total = "" + total;

Actually you are creating 2 new string objects first for `""` and second `str_total`

but in my code only `one new string object` will be created.

Implementation of valueOf in String class is as follows -

```
   public static String valueOf(int i) {
        return Integer.toString(i);
    }
```

here toString will create a new String object

Comment: please explain how the code is optimized than my code? i mean fast running and memory/object utilization.

Comment: Thanks for answer i go with String.valueOf(int).

Answer (score 1):

The `String.valueOf(int)` method calls `Integer.toString(int)`.

Doing string concatenation (`""+i`), first `i` is converted to an `Integer` and then the function `Integer.toString` is called to get `String` value of the integer.

Therefor calling `String.valueOf(int)` will perform better than string concatenation since it skips the creation of the `Integer` object.

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation .i go with String.valueOf(int).

Answer (score 0):

```
String str_total = String.valueOf(total);
```

`String.valueOf(int)` is more efficient than `""+int` so prefer to use `String.valueOf(int)`

Refer [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/stringvalueofint-vs-int) link for measurement in performance .

In Jdk > 1.5  you can also use this.

```
String str_total= String.format ("%d", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to do it:

```
int intValue = 1;    
String str1 = String.format("%d", intValue);
```

You can also control how the value is shown (leading zeros, base, etc). Find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

The cool thing about this is, that in my opinion, this

```
String str2 = String.format("Blabla %d blupp %dm etc", intValue1, intValue2);
```

looks much more readable (if you are familiar with the formats), then

```
String str3 = "Balbla " + intValue1 + " blupp " + intValue2 + "m etc";
```

(+ you get more control over how it's shown).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Integer` cannot hold such big values which will cause it to be represented with the scientific notation I think that

```
Integer.toString()
```

will totally work.

If you want to format your number in some way you should use `NumberFormat` like this:

```
Integer myInt = 31535468;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
String myString = nf.format(myInt);
```

I think that using `NumberFormat` is the most conventional way here.